# Sum value If date are between multiple range of dates (matrix)

Tags: excel, date, sum, range, between

[Excel Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FULcA.jpg)

Hello,

I need to sum the values on column D **if** the date on cell A2 is **inside** the range **E2:F5** (matrix?).

For the example on the picture (Excel Print) the result is 6 (1+5).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS() is the formula to use:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,E:E,"<=" & A2,F:F,">=" &A2)
```

[image]

Comment: It is amazing.. @Scott Carner

Comment: @MJSuriya please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly!

Comment: Oops.. Hah... @scott.. I didnt asked it.. So I could not marked it as correct one. But i think #nioxys marked it as right one. :) :) Happy day